# What is the total bond energy of CO2?

Tags: bond

How can you calculate the total bond energy of CO2? I've searched for the bond energy of C=O and found it was 745, but sometimes 799. Which one is the right one to use? And do those numbers mean the bond energy of CO2?

Comment: there are many C=O bonds with different chemical environments, bearing slightly different energies. Usually the reported value is an average of many instances of that bond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking a pretty complex question. The short answer is that to calculate such an energy you have to utilize quantum mechanical calculations, or otherwise perform macroscopic experiments on bulk $\ce{CO2}$.

A quick ab-initio calculation of a O=C=O molecule with bond-length 1.164 Angstroems (quite close to experimental and theoretically deduced length) yields the following Hartree-Fock SCF energy (using the 6-31G* basis set):

`-187.634176090515 Hartrees, which is
-492633.5668524824 kJ/mol`

This is a huge negative energy, and rightly so -- it is how much energy is theoretically required to break the $\ce{CO2}$ molecule entirely into subatomic particles. In other words, it is the energy holding $\ce{CO2}$ together -- the energy that defines the molecule.

Better approximations can be made with higher levels of theory but don't deviate from these values by much.

The simplistic route is to add up collective bonds from a data table provided in your textbook, e.g. $2 \times$ C=O = total molecular bond energy. This is not the same thing as the total molecular energy though: the latter includes energetic contribution of the nuclear-electron interactions, not just atomic bonds.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't worry too much about the slight differences in the bond enthalpy for the C$=$O. I will discuss why after the next paragraph.

The bond enthalpy is the amount of energy (in kJ) that is required to break 1 mol of that bond. Therefore, it is also a measurement of how much energy is released as 1 mol of that same bond is formed. The bond enthalpy is dependent upon the strength of the bond. The higher the strength, the larger the bond enthalpy.

The bond enthalpy is more of an average value than an accurate figure. For example, the energy required to break the first double bond between the central carbon atom and the oxygen is different from the energy required to break the second double bond. This is because the strength of the bond is dependent upon its environment. When you break off that first oxygen atom, it changes the environment.

So you can use any one of the those bond enthalpy values.

**Source(s):** Any good textbook in general Chemistry should discuss how enthalpy bonds are calculated. Personally, I used the *Pearson Baccalaureate Textbook for IB Chemistry HL*

Comment: Thanks! This helped. But what is the total bond energy of CO2?

Comment: In $\ce{CO2}$, the potential energy in the carbon-oxygen double bonds is equal to the number of such bonds in the molecule multiplied with the average bond enthalpy. 

If you are in doubt, it is always useful to draw the Lewis Structure of the molecule to help define the bonds.

Answer (score -1):

I know that at this point I'm basically necroposting, but none of these answers actually directly answered the question, which was disappointing since I came here looking for the answer to this same question, and yet after 7 years, nobody actually answered it.

Lets address the question actually being asked:
**"What is the total bond energy of CO2"** and lets notice that he's referring to chemical bonds, not nuclear/subatomic bond energies since he also said: **" I've searched for the bond energy of C=O and found it was 745, but sometimes 799. Which one is the right one to use?"**

Ok, so now we have a question that we can actually answer.
To start off, carbon forms 2 double bonds with oxygen atoms like this **O=C=O** which makes sense since carbon has 4 more valence electrons than a full shell and oxygen has 2 less than a full outer shell. I often like to informally write atoms with their valence electrons written like such: **C+4 O-2** since it makes it easier to see where they are relative to a full shell.
Anyway, so to make any stable molecule with this notation, you just have to make it neutral, so this means 2 oxygens and one carbon: **2x(-2) + 1x(4) = 0.**

Now, this molecule has 2 essentially identical double bonds O=C=O on either side of the carbon, and the energy of one of these bonds is what we are looking for, or more correctly, the average energy between both of the double bonds present. now technically speaking they have the same strength, but practically speaking, one of the double bonds will come off first when involved in a chemical reaction, meaning that the other double bond will experience a change in strength since the molecule as a whole is now significantly different. we would have to account for this, but this is usually what most online values will already be. generally they display the average value, that is as long as they say that collectively "C=O bonds in CO2 = X kJ/mol" with no further information on individual bonds.
another thing to mention is that **C=O bonds in CO2 will have a different strength than C=O bonds in other molecules,** and for the same reason as earlier, its because the molecules are significantly different.
and another thing we have to watch out for is whether the value we find online or elsewhere is for the molecule as a whole (both double bonds) or for only one of the double bonds, but usually that is easy to tell as it will either say **"per mol of CO2"** which is both, or **"per mol of C=O"** which is only one, and likely the averaged value.

Now, as I said at the start, I too am looking for the same answer, meaning that I don't have a definitive answer for you that I can whip out of my back pocket on demand. however, I can walk you through my logic on how to find a more accurate and satisfactory answer, which is precisely what I did.

When we search for the value online, we get a lot of the same 2 answers you got, one around ~750 and another about ~800. this difference is large enough to cause error in calculations, and so a more accurate answer is necessary. now if we look a little deeper we'll find that **the sites offering the 750 value are primarily discussing carbonyl groups.** such as: [The Carbonyl Group - Chemistry Libre Texts](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Organic_Chemistry/Supplemental_Modules_(Organic_Chemistry)/Aldehydes_and_Ketones/Properties_of_Aldehydes_and_Ketones/The_Carbonyl_Group#:%7E:text=The%20double%20bond%20lengths%20of,-179%20kcal%2Fmol)
These are C=O groups *within* other molecules. and now if we refer to Wikipedia: [Carbon-oxygen bond - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon%E2%80%93oxygen_bond) (I know its not always perfectly reliable, but well known science data is usually accurately represented) we will find the following paragraph:

> "Bond lengths of C=O bonds are around 123 pm in carbonyl compounds. The C=O bond length in carbon dioxide is 116 pm. The C=O bonds in acyl halides have partial triple bond character and are consequently very short: 117 pm."

**Notice the bond lengths.** they are 123pm for carbonyl compounds, 116pm for carbon dioxide, and 117pm for acyl halides. If you remember, the shorter the bond length, usually the significantly *stronger* the bond. CO2 actually has the shortest bond length here, even surpassing the acyl halides with their sort-of triple bond character, and triple bonds are some of the strongest in all of chemistry, such as N≡N (nitrogen gas) and C≡O (carbon monoxide). this means that **of all the values for C=O bonds in various molecules, the one for CO2 should most likely have the highest bond strength of all of them.** also, generally speaking, simpler binary compounds such as CO2 will have some of the strongest bonds, such as the C≡O from earlier (which was conveniently similar to CO2).

There is however, one last thing we should check, and that is whether the values from earlier refer to the individual C=O bonds in CO2 or the whole molecule of CO2. now, we already have a bit of a hint, since the carbonyl groups from earlier were said to have the 750 value, and carbonyl groups are individual C=O bonds, not CO2 molecules, this means that 750 must be the value for a single C=O carbonyl bond. we also know that the carbonyl bonds should be a little less strong than the CO2 bonds. now, if either the 750 or 800 value were for a whole CO2 molecule, then when you split that in half (~400) to look at only one of the C=O bonds, it would be *less* strong than the carbonyl bonds (~400 < 750-800) which we know isn't true. **therefore, the 750-800 value is for only *one* individual C=O bond in CO2.**

Time for conclusions:
**We know that the 750-800 values are per bond, and we know that the 750 value belongs to the carbonyl groups, and we know that CO2 has a shorter bond length on average than the carbonyl groups, and therefore likely higher bond strength, meaning that the most likely answer to your question is that the 800 value belongs to CO2 and that the bond strength in kJ/mol of individual C=O bonds for CO2 is ~800 kJ/mol. that would be 1,600kJ/mol of CO2 molecules, that's 1.6MJ/mol of carbon dioxide, now that's a lot of energy!**

Comment: CO2 is a too complex molecule to perform such a back of the envelope calculation. Unfortunately this post is very long, without saying much. I don't actually think it's answering the question. But then again the question is really hard to answer.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン thanks for the feedback, as I'm quite new here and would like to refine my ability to answer questions effectively. however I should point out that my post did not claim to definitively answer the question, it was only meant to point people in the right direction. I was also later able to find more definitive references which aligned very closely with my answer.